# Why does my HTML and JS not work?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get this to work on my public webpage. I've made sure all permissions on files are correct, but when I go to the site, it just shows a blank page.  It's supposed to have a matrix-like effect. I edited it through Codepen.io, but when I transfer it over to actual files and upload them, nothing works.

HTML:

```
<html><head>

<script src="(link the js file attached that is in the directory of my webpage)" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Matrix</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
    </canvas><br/><br/>  
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
//this is my matrix.js file

$(document).ready(function(){
var s=window.screen;
var width = canvas.width=s.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var inLink = false;
var yPositions = Array(300).join(0).split('');
var context=canvas.getContext('2d');
var draw = function () {
   context.fillStyle='rgba(0,0,0,.05)';
   context.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
context.fillStyle='#0F0';
canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", on_mousemove, false);
context.fillText(linkText,10,50);
context.font = '12pt Georgia';
yPositions.map(function(y, index){
text = String.fromCharCode(1e3+Math.random()*33);//determines characters randomly from this specific font
x = (index * 10)+10;
canvas.getContext('2d').fillText(text, x, y);
if(y > 100 + Math.random()*1e4)
{
  yPositions[index]=0;
}
else
{
  yPositions[index] = y + 10;
}
});
};
RunMatrix();
function RunMatrix()
{
   if(typeof Game_Interval != "undefined") clearInterval(Game_Interval);
    Game_Interval = setInterval(draw, 33);
 }
 })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include your javascript files ***after*** the libraries they depend upon

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="(link the js file attached that is in the directory of my webpage)" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, consider using a newer version of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

try adding...

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
```

at the start of your $(document).ready function...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
....
```

basically you are referencing 'canvas', which doesn't appear to exist yet..

also make sure you're including jquery before any libraries or scripts that attempt to use it!